# Google app engine entity gets deleted agter 7 days

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm using Google cloud for back end of my Android app. 
I save an entity:

```
ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(greeting).now();
```

But after 7 days the entity gets deleted from the datastore. 
I want to keep them forever, or at least for much longer period.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your entity definition and setup so that I can refine my answers?

Comment: I'm using this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore with some very small changes. To get the list of entities in my app I use auto generated GreetingEndpoint from Android Studio

Comment: I don't know for sure that the period is 7 days, or it is just a coincidence, I'll now tomorrow

Comment: Did you check in your admin console (either local http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin or in you appengine account) what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you reuse an entity's id and therefor overwrite the existing entity yourself every 7 days (well or a web crawler does).

Take a look at the datastore in the developers console. You should see only a few writes to your entity, but if i'm right you'll see something like 5 writes and more (the actual write count depends on the amount of indexes defined in your entity).

To make sure this doesn't happen you can simply set the `@Id Long id` property of your greeting to `null` before you call `save()` so you'll get an auto generated id.

Comment: I have:
    Parent 
    Id
    public Long id;
    Index
    public Date date;
    Index
    public int rating = 0;
    Index
    public Long views = 0l;
According to the tutorial the id is auto generated without setting it to null before every save.

Comment: that is correct. The default value of Long is null, so you don't have to set it for newly created Objects. If you load an entity though and save it you will overwrite the existing entity.